# unrecognized syntax identifier "proto3". This parser only recognizes "proto2" on Linkerd

Tags: protocol-buffers, protoc, linkerd

I have cloned linkerd (https://github.com/linkerd) repo on my linux ubuntu, and installed protoc, version 2.5. When I try to compile the linkerd using the following command I get the error "unrecognized syntax identifier "proto3". This parser only recognizes "proto2".

command: `./sbt linkerd/compile`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to install `protoc` version 3.x to compile proto3 files. Version 2.5 is over four years old.

Many distros have Protobuf packages available for easy installation, or you can install from source as described here: 
https://github.com/google/protobuf/blob/master/src/README.md

Comment: it says it doesn't recognizes, so I downgraded! anyways let me try that again

Comment: Can you please create a tag on stackoverflow named "linkerd" please? Here's the official repo for it
https://github.com/linkerd/linkerd
we don't have enough reputation to create one

Comment: You add thenew tag to my question.
-gracias!

Comment: @zillani it wasn't me.